# Can't login with Mysql root account but can login when use sudo command in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Can't login with Mysql root account but can login when use sudo command in ubuntu 16.04

```
bluebird:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
bluebird:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
bluebird:~$ sudo mysql -uroot
[sudo] password for bluebird: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 21
Server version: 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

When I use **mysql -u root -p**, I can't login. When I use **sudo mysql -u root**, i can.

And I don't have the password for the root user of MySQL.

I don't know why.

Comment: Do you by chance have a .my.cnf file in /root containing the root password?

Comment: you are inserting incorrect password of root

Comment: Hi, @mwp, just checked, there no such file under my /root

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, actually, i removed my root password...

Comment: @bluebird_lboro Are you sure you have a password set?? Try `mysql -u root` without sudo.

Comment: how did you remove it?

Comment: @mwp as I mentioned, I can't login with mysql -u root, but i can with sudo mysql -u root.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, can't recall exactly how I remove it....:(

Comment: try this @bluebird_lboro http://superuser.com/questions/957708/mysql-mariadb-error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: No, you said you tried `sudo mysql -u root` and `mysql -u root -p`. I'm asking you to try `mysql -u root`. Three different commands.

Comment: Ok @mwp, sorry about that. but I have tried mysql -u root, it does not work. actually you can see it on the result I put in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the command below:

```
use mysql;
select User, Host from user;
```

It turns out, somehow I got 'root'@'XXXXX-aspire','root'@'localhost' and 'root'@'%'.

When I delete 'root'@'XXXXX-aspire', I can login by `mysql -uroot` without problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this as SUDO
then try login without sudo

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*  TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```